# Wrap-around MCU memory map definition with negative addresses

Tags: ghidra

I figured it'd be more appropriate to ask this question here:

https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/2530#issuecomment-785007613

Given this linear address space a particular MCU:

[image: V850 mem space]

It's not easily definable as-is on the memory manager, see:

```
memory = currentProgram.getMemory()
fb = memory.getAllFileBytes()   
blk = memory.getBlock(toAddr(0x0))
memory.removeBlock(blk, monitor)

memory.createUninitializedBlock("internal_ram",toAddr(0x3ff8000),0x2fff,False)
memory.createUninitializedBlock("peripherals", toAddr(0x3ffefff),0xfff, False)
memory.createInitializedBlock("rom", toAddr(0x0), fb[0], 0, 0x1000000, False)
disassemble(toAddr(0x0))
```

Yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
    at ghidra.program.database.mem.MemoryMapDB.checkBlock(MemoryMapDB.java:1043)
    at ghidra.program.database.mem.MemoryMapDB.removeBlock(MemoryMapDB.java:1850)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Blocks do not belong to this program
ghidra.program.database.mem.MemoryBlockDB@6f03ae13
ghidra.program.database.mem.MemoryBlockDB@38d5ac1c
ghidra.program.database.mem.MemoryBlockDB@6ad8b9ac
```

What would be the correct sequence of arguments/flags/(instruction ordering?) to have a correct representation of a loaded V850 16MB firmware (size 0x1000000) on Ghidra? What am I doing wrong?

[Here's the MCU PDF address space section for reference](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/files/6035639/nec-.PD703128-mem-address-1.pdf)

Comment: If it's really Ghidra-specific it might be better handled over there. If you think it's a generic RE problem, please state it as such and provide the actual question instead of a link which may be wrong or dead in several years.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I thought that the `ghidra` tag was meant for specific Ghidra questions as I was directed here a while ago in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65314484/clear-several-functions-with-options#comment116289824_65314484

Comment: sure we can (try to) answer RE questions in the context of Ghidra. But this is not an official support site for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note to self, when running `memory.removeBlock(blk, monitor)` make sure that the memory map is not empty from previous wipes/redefinitions (iterations of the script).

In other words, opening a file creates a default memory map, but the script wasn't contemplating the case where the address map was empty to begin with.